# cakephp 2 cookie not working with Chrome or IE only

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cakephp

I have a weird problem that only seems to be happening in chrome. Basically I'm setting a cookie to remember an id so I can present my users with the correct info when they visit my site.

In my controller action:

```
$currentcookie = $this->Cookie->read('mixes');
if ($currentcookie == '') {
    //write a new cookie with a new id etc
} else {
    //show them info relating to the id in the cookie
}
```

So if it's the first visit by someone if ($currentcookie == '') should evaluate to true and a new cookie should be created. If there's already a cookie 'else' gets run.

I output the id in the view so I know if it's a newly created one, which it should be on the first visit but should stay the same on subsequent visits.

This works on FF Opera and safari, but weirdly not with chrome or IE. I'm not closing the browser or anything. What am I missing?

**NEW --- Here's how I'm reading and writing the cookie:**

```
$currentcookie = $this->Cookie->read('mixes'); 

$this->Cookie->write('mixes', array('idofthemix' => $newTempMixId));
```

In my appController I have in the before filter:

```
    $this->Cookie->name = 'tempmix';
    $this->Cookie->time = '30 days';  // or '1 hour'
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'localhost';
    $this->Cookie->key = 'li8&*^iih^456%$^%$fsgatfjmi@#@##@@:LLLkjljkjlj87^*&^*6768!£"&^*()%$&';
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
```

So it shows up in most browsers as tempmix[mixes] with a value like Q2FrZQ%3D%3D.b8LRe4GareCnq54%3D. just not in Chrome or IE

Comment: Is it possible that the name "id" is conflicting with some other cookie being set in the problem browsers? does it change anything if you use a truly unique identifier like "jgfchgmf655-id"?

Comment: Nope that doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: @crazysarah How are you _writing_ the cookie

Comment: @Colin - I've added a little more to the Qu - thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: is you php file in `ANSI` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser settings, sometimes the browser is set to not allow any cookies.

also, try to go manually to the cookies list in each browser, and see if your site cookies does exists or not. (every browser will have a different way of accessing the cookies)

It might be worth to note that, some security software, like antiviruses or internet security suits, might be messing with the way the browser is transmitting the request.

**EDIT**

After the edit, try the following:

```
$currentcookie = unserialize($this->Cookie->read('mixes')); 

$this->Cookie->write('mixes', serialize(array('idofthemix' => $newTempMixId)));
```

Comment: If I right click and inspect element on chrome while on my page I can go to resources and see that in fact the cookie I expected to be there isn't. However the one from CAKEPHP is there, so the browser must be accepting it. Why wouldn't it work for my custom cookie?

Comment: @crazysarah the last thing I can think of is that you should make sure that cookies are sent before headers are finished sending, and before any other output is sent, trying to set a cookie after any output is already sent will fail, this would be the reason for some cookies to be fine and some to be not set.

Comment: **sorry for delay in replying - got really late! I have tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work. Plus is giving me an error: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. I continue to investigate, any more ideas?

Comment: Hey there, in case it helps anyone else, it seems the configs in my AppControllers beforeFilter for the cookie (see my question) were causing the problem in someway. I think it was the name. Either way works now! WooHoo!